# Running actions when I disconnect external monitor

Tags: macos, display, script

I would love to auto start [Bartender](http://macbartender.com) (by the way, excellent app that hides some of your notification area icons) when I unplug my external monitor from my Mac.

Is there any app or script that could do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/). It allows you to trigger various actions, including launching applications, based on a variety of "evidence sources" (which include which monitors are connected). Have a look at the [full feature list](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/feature-list/), but it should accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: This is PERFECT. Managed to implement what I wanted in a few minutes after installing. Thanks!